# PHPUnit + Selenium 2: Action on ajax load

Tags: php, ajax, selenium, phpunit, automated-tests

During test I need to do following:

- Click button which leads to ajax request and redirect after that
- Check that user has been redirected to correct page

My Code:

```php
$this->byId('reg_email')->value('test@example.com');
$this->byId('reg_password')->value('seecret');
// No form here, so i can't just call submit()
// This click invokes ajax request
$this->byId('reg_submit')->click();

// Check page content (this page should appear after redirect)
$msg = $this->byCssSelector('h1')->text();
$this->assertEquals('Welcome!', $msg);
```

Problem

- Message check goes right after click, not before ajax request and page redirect

Solution, I do not like:

- Add `sleep(3);` before content check.

I do not like it because:

- It is silly
- In case of fast responses I am going to lose time, in case of long requests I am going to get content check before ajax request finishes.

I wonder, is there any way to track ajax request+refresh and check for content just in time?

My setup:

- PHP 5.4, 5.5 also available
- PHPUnit 3.8
- Selenium RC integration for PHPUnit 1.3.1
- Selenium-server-standalone 2.33.0
- Windows 7 x64
- JRE 7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, there is a kind of solution, I do not really like it, but it is something instead of nothing.

The idea is to use more smart "sleep", there is a method `waitUntil()` which takes an `anonymous function` and `timeout` in milliseconds. What is does - runs this passed function in loop until timeout hits or your function return `True`. So you can run something and wait until context is changed:

```php
$this->waitUntil(function () {
    if ($this->byCssSelector('h1')) {
        return true;
    }
    return null;
}, 5000);
```

I still will be glad if somebody give better solution.

Comment: This fails into a memory leak.

Comment: This works well actually, it works almost the same as a implicitWait.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not sure if it can be usefull for you, but you can try to use this :

```
$this->timeouts()->implicitWait(20000);
```